# Vue components not rendering when @nuxtjs/storybook is used in a Vue Storefront Next project - possibly a Typescript issue?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, storybook

I am trying to use [@nuxtjs/storybook](https://storybook.nuxtjs.org/) inside a Vue Storefront Next (https://docs.vuestorefront.io/v2/general/key-concepts.html) project.

I can get Storybook to open and to show stories, but the component within the stories are not rendered. For example, if I try and use the example from https://storybook.nuxtjs.org/usage then I see a `<link>` element in devtools (the name of the Vue component), not a rendered `<a>` element (the content of the Vue component):

[image: Screenshot 2021-02-23 at 11 13 15]

I then switched to trying to use another simple component:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-pine-2byq7?file=/components/Logo.vue
- https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-pine-2byq7?file=/components/Logo.stories.js

But that doesn't work either, you can see an example of that here: https://pedantic-chandrasekhar-a83cfc.netlify.app/?path=/story/logo--logo (I had trouble getting Storybook to work on Codesandbox).

Vue Storefront Next is based on Nuxt but I had to make a few changes to get Storybook to open:

1. Update the `build` section within `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
babel: {
      presets({ envName }) {
        return [
          [
            '@nuxt/babel-preset-app',
            {
              corejs: { version: 3 }
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      ignore: [/[\/\\]core-js/, /@babel[\/\\]runtime/],
    },
```

2. install `@babel/runtime-corejs3`, `core-js` 3, and `ts-node`

`ts-node` was necessary because Vue Storefront Next provides a `tsconfig.json` file for development of part of the project, and that makes @nuxtjs/storybook module think the project is a Typescript project (https://github.com/nuxt-community/storybook/blob/e5b3698482873d7129cd763a0422b8c3151cee0b/src/index.ts#L67-L76), but the Vue Storefront project does not use `@nuxt/typescript-runtime` - I am wondering if this is part of the problem?

You can see the package.json content on Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-pine-2byq7?file=/package.json

---

Any clues as to how to fix this issue would be SUPER appreciated, thank you! I've spent the best part of a day on this but I don't know enough about Storybook or Nuxt to be able to debug it myself, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the `@nuxtjs/storybook` module seems to be dependent on `components: true` being set in the project's `nuxt.config.js` file.

This isn't mentioned anywhere in the `@nuxtjs/storybook` documentation, but I've raised a Github issue to point this out and will raise a PR against the docs if the maintainer agrees.

You can see my thought process behind how I discovered this issue in this Github thread: https://github.com/nuxt-community/storybook/issues/233#issuecomment-785027558